# Addition operator for types with common operator() methods

Tags: c++

I have two structs `A` and `B` for whom I've defined an `operator()(int x)` which returns a `std::vector<int>`. In my templated calling function `f<C>(int x)`, I'd like to be able to overload the addition operator `+` for the types `A` and `B` to mean the concatenation of the vectors returned by their `operator()(int x)` methods. How can I accomplish this?

```
#include <vector>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

struct A {
    std::vector<int> operator()(int x) {
        std::vector<int> v = {1*x, 2*x};
        return v;
    }
};

struct B {
    std::vector<int> operator()(int x) {
        std::vector<int> v = {3*x, 4*x};
        return v;
    }
};

template <typename C>
void f(int x) {
    fmt::print("{}\n", C()(x));
}

int main() {
    using C = A + B; // preferred syntax
    f<C>(1); // expected output: [1,2,3,4]
}
```

Post-Comment Addition:

As perhaps alluded to by the commenters, if I get rid of the templated function, I can certainly do this, and it works,

```
#include <vector>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <functional>

struct A {
    std::vector<int> operator()(int x) {
        std::vector<int> v = {1*x, 2*x};
        return v;
    }
};

struct B {
    std::vector<int> operator()(int x) {
        std::vector<int> v = {3*x, 4*x};
        return v;
    }
};

using FUNC = std::function<std::vector<int>(int)>;

FUNC operator+(FUNC &f1, FUNC &f2) {
    return [f1, f2](int x) {
        std::vector<int> v1 = f1(x);
        std::vector<int> v2 = f2(x);
        std::vector<int> v3;
        v3.reserve(v1.size() + v2.size());
        v3.insert(v3.end(), v1.begin(), v1.end());
        v3.insert(v3.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
        return v3;
    };
}

void f(FUNC &F, int x) {
    fmt::print("{}\n", F(x));
}

int main() {
    FUNC F1 = A();
    FUNC F2 = B();
    auto F = F1 + F2;
    f(F, 1);
}
```

but I want to know *definitively* if operator overloading for types ala `using C = A + B;` is even possible in `c++`?

Comment: Why the template function if you use only `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: This is a simplified example; my code requires the template(s).

Comment: I don't understabd your code... How can work `using C = A + B;`? `using` should expect a type but the `+` operator works on instances. How can you define a `+` operator, which takes 2 instances of `A` and `B`, combining the 2 `()` operator which takes a `int`?

Comment: @marital_weeping `using C = A + B;` is **invalid C++**. It doesn't even make sense. Refer to a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn about C++ syntax.

Comment: After edit - so your goal is essentially to make a functors aggregator, and your question is whether it can be done via aliases instead of manual implementation? If so, the answer is **no**, an alias cannot introduce a new functionality

Comment: @The Dreams Wind, yeah that sounds about right.  I guess I'll have to change my implementation from using the template to using std::function as above.

Comment: This sounds like an attempt to write a program is some other, completely unrelated language but using C++ syntax. The end result will eventually be something that neither someone who's experienced in the other language, nor anyone who's experienced in C++, could possibly understand.

Comment: That's deep Sam.